# Use of AvroStorage() in pig

Tags: java, apache-pig, avro

I'm trying to build my first Pig UDF in Java and am having trouble calling the function when building with Eclipse 
My code looks like this:

```
REGISTER /home/user2/deb/demo.jar;
```

REGISTER /home/user2/deb/deb/avro-1.4.0.jar
REGISTER /home/user2/deb/deb/json-simple-1.1.jar
REGISTER /home/user2/deb/deb/piggybank.jar
REGISTER /home/user2/deb/jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar
REGISTER /home/user2/deb//jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.5.jar

```
avro = LOAD '/user/user2/deb/part-r-00000.avro' USING AvroStorage('schema_check') AS (accntNo: chararray);
```

C = FOREACH avro GENERATE masking.AccountMask(accntNo);
DUMP C;

```
ERROR 1070: Could not resolve AvroStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instantiate:AvroStorage
at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:459)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the avro runtime jar:  avro-1.5.3.jar.  You might be running a different avro version than 1.5.3, so check to make sure you put the right version number in there.

register /some/path/avro-1.5.3.jar

Comment: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected

Comment: previously i was using wrong piggybank.jar,now that problem has been solved

Comment: So not sure what problems remain, if any?

Comment: yes it's showing the following exception now ExecException: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected

Comment: can anyone give me the link to download piggybank-0.9.0 or 0.10.0 jars.Please help me asap

Comment: Aha, that means you have a hadoop library conflict. In Hadoop 1.2.1 TaskAttemptContext is a class, but in 2.1.0 it is an interface. Make sure you are using the hadoop core and hadoop common libraries that _come with your hadoop distribution_ when compiling stuff for Hadoop. Essentially, you need to replace the hadoop jars you are currently using with what is used on your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fully qualified name for AvroStorage:

```
avro = LOAD '/user/user2/deb/part-r-00000.avro' 
       USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage('schema_check') 
       AS (accntNo: chararray);
```